# How to get the menu items from an existing menu in maya

Tags: maya, mel

Hi I have the question of how to find the menu items of an specific menu and put the in a list

for example:

I want to find the menu items of the menu $Mymenu
($Mymenu is a costum menu i made with other code and each time I open maya it is created)

I'm doing somthing like:

```
menu -itemArray $Mymenu
```

but it only give me an string with the full name of the menu instead of the itesm in the menu:

```
scriptEditorPanel1Window|TearOffPane|scriptEditorPanel1|MayaWindow_menu32
```

so I want to know if there is a way to get all menu items from any menu already made in maya??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the query flag.

```
menu -q -ia $myMenu
```